# Python EWS GetFolder request is always invalid

Tags: python, soap, exchangewebservices, suds

Hi Stackoverflow community!

I'm trying to work with Python suds and [ewsclient](https://bitbucket.org/dholth/ewsclient) to talk to Exchange. I created a small prog, which seems to send the right soap message, but it is always rejected by the Exchange server.

The [python code for this request is on gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d13f2ec40653c855cf3c).

Soap Message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns2:GetFolder>
         <ns2:FolderShape>
            <ns0:BaseShape>Default</ns0:BaseShape>
         </ns2:FolderShape>
         <ns2:FolderIds>
            <ns0:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox"/>
         </ns2:FolderIds>
      </ns2:GetFolder>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorInvalidRequest</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="de-AT">The request is invalid.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorInvalidRequest</e:ResponseCode>
                <e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The request is invalid.</e:Message>
            </detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The only difference between my request and the [MS developer documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/aa580274(v=exchg.150).aspx) are the namespace prefixes.

Any ideas on what's wrong with that request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested a lot and found out that somehow Exchange does not like the             `<ns0:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox"/>` element. If I remove it, I won't get an invalid request response, but that the folderIds are missing.

It seems like SUDS is not really maintained any more and I even tried to use suds jurko, but I got similar issues. So a lot of work, and not really a useable way to use EWS SOAP with python.

It seems like I have to switch back for that prog to Groovy and Java.

Answer (score 0):

Another difference is you're including an empty `Header` element. Have you tried leaving that out?

Answer (score 0):

i'm trying to test these endpoints on postman. and here is how i did successfully ( with NTLM authentication and editing default Content-Type header to text/xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:types="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" 
 xmlns:msgs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
 >
   <soap:Body>
      <msgs:GetFolder>
         <msgs:FolderShape>
            <types:BaseShape>Default</types:BaseShape>
         </msgs:FolderShape>
         <msgs:FolderIds>
            <types:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox"/>
         </msgs:FolderIds>
      </msgs:GetFolder>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and another one worked for me for getting user's avatar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" 
 xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
 >
    <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
        <t:MailboxCulture>en-US</t:MailboxCulture>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <m:GetUserPhoto>
            <m:Email>name.surmame@companymail.com</m:Email>
            <m:SizeRequested>HR48x48</m:SizeRequested>
        </m:GetUserPhoto>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```